# UITableView Cells With DIfferent Format & Behavior in Same Table Section

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView with one section.  All of the cells in that one section have cells that are derived from a subclass of UITableViewCell called PLContactCell.

What I'd like to do is, for the very last row of the table only, not use a PLContactCell.  I just want to use a normal UITableViewCell that I can format however I would like. I'd also like to be able to have this cell NOT respond to being tapped.

My initial cellForRowAtIndexPath method is:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

PLContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[PLContactCell   reuseIdentifier]];

  if (!cell) {
      cell = [PLContactCell reusableCell];
      cell.delegate = self;
  }

  id modelObject = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if ([modelObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    [cell configureWithString:modelObject];
  } else {
      [cell configureWithUser:modelObject];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

**EDIT**
So I tried created a UITableView cell in the XIB file and added the reuse identifier of "newCell" to it.  Then I added this code:

```
if (indexPath.row == [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] - 1) {
         NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newCell";
         noFormatCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

This doesn't do anything. My question is, how do I access the last row of the section and how do I make it so that that cell it is not a PLContactCell but a UITableView Cell.

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: maybe at the beginning of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you could compare (indexPath.row + 1) to [tableView numberOfRowInSection:indexPath.section] so you know if you are at the last cell. And if so, call another cell. but consider Derek answer that appears to be what you need

Comment: @TimothyMoose: My question is, how do I access the last row of the section and how do I make it so that that cell it is not a PLContactCell but a UITableView Cell.

Comment: Can you clarify "this doesn't do anything"? For example, are you entering the conditional block or not? It would be helpful if you could include your updates `cellForRowAtIndexPath` in it's entirety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's always at the end, you might consider using the footer view of the UITableView.  You can then keep some extra logic out of your UITableViewDataSource.

If it HAS to be as a cell, you'd have to add an extra row count on your last section, then do an if statement check to watch out for it in your -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: implementation.  I would strongly urge you try the footer approach, as it's cleaner and way easier to figure out what you were doing a few months/years from now.

Here's some code.  Note you'd need to make another section if you are using grouped style in the UITableView.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
   if (section == sections.count - 1)  //Looking for last section
   {
      return [sections objectAtIndex:section].count + 1; //Add one to the last section
   }

   return [sections objectAtIndex:section].count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSInteger row = indexPath.row;


   if ((sections.count == indexPath.section) && [sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section].count == indexPath.row)
   {
       //Here you would create and return your UITableViewCell
   }

PLContactCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:[PLContactCell   reuseIdentifier]];

  if (!cell) {
      cell = [PLContactCell reusableCell];
      cell.delegate = self;
  }

  id modelObject = [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  if ([modelObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    [cell configureWithString:modelObject];
  } else {
      [cell configureWithUser:modelObject];
  }

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd prefer to do the footer, but I am not in charge of the project and apparently it needs to be a cell.  Right now I have: if (indexPath.row == [[sections objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] count] - 1) {
         NSString *CellIdentifier = @"newCell";
         noFormatCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } But this doesn't do anything. I created a cell in the nib with that cell identifier - I'm not sure how to code this.